# How to expose spaCy as a REST API?

Tags: python, rest, spacy

I am interested in using the spaCy python library for my own open source project. What I am searching for is a REST-based API. What is necessary or what is the recommended way to expose the spaCy API via a common REST interface? I already took a look into the [spaCy services](https://github.com/explosion/spacy-services) and the [spacy-api-docker project form jgontrum](https://github.com/jgontrum/spacy-api-docker). But it seems there is no offical REST API available and everyone have to do it by himself. If so, what is the best way to wrap a python spaCy method/script into a REST API? There seems to be frameworks like [falcon](https://falconframework.org/), [hug](http://www.hug.rest/) and [flask](https://github.com/pallets/flask/) to help me in doing this.

But is it the recommended approach to write my own REST API server with one of these frameworks or is there something I have overseen and spaCy is already available via a REST API interface?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

spaCy is not deeply tied to any framework, so you can choose your favorite and use it.

---

Another option you might consider is [FastAPI](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi). For example, here's a simple spaCy entity recognition API:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel
import spacy

nlp_en = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
app = FastAPI()


class Data(BaseModel):
    text: str


@app.post("/text/")
def extract_entities(data: Data, lang: str):
    doc_en = nlp_en(data.text)
    ents = []
    for ent in doc_en.ents:
        ents.append({"text": ent.text, "label_": ent.label_})
    return {"message": data.text, "lang": lang, "ents": ents}
```

And the automatic docs UI looks like this:

[image: FastAPI docs UI]

Disclaimers: I created FastAPI, and that's what we currently use at Explosion (the creators of spaCy).

Comment: What about scalability? In understand that the way you are proposing is the most straightforward way, and quickly deployable. But the ideal case is to separate the logic that receives the web api that is supposed to be responsible for receiving thousands of requests at the same time, and so called 'nlp worker' which should be doing heavy work that requires extra care for scalability.